# GraphQL Args error: argument type must be Input Type but got: function GraphQLObjectType(config) {

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

On server start (`node index.js`) I am getting the following error with my GraphQL NodeJS server:

> Error: Query.payment(data:) argument type must be Input Type but got:
>   function GraphQLObjectType(config) {
>       _classCallCheck(this, GraphQLObjectType);

This error happened when I changed my original args from a string

```
        args: {
            data: { type: graphQL.GraphQLString }
        },
```

To an object type:

```
        args: {
            data: { type: graphQL.GraphQLObjectType }
        },
```

I need an object type as I need to send several fields as params.

**GraphQL Server:**

```
var Query = new graphQL.GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: {
        payment: {
            type: graphQL.GraphQLString,
            args: {
                data: { type: graphQL.GraphQLObjectType }
            },
            resolve: function (_, args) {
                // There will be more data here, 
                // but ultimately I want to return a string
                return 'success!';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

How can I allow it to accept an object?

---

**Frontend** (if needed. But the error is happening before I even send this):

```
var userQuery = encodeURIComponent('{ payment ( data: { user : "test" } )}');

$.get('http://localhost:4000/graphql?query=' + userQuery, function (res) {
       //stuff
});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want use Object as an argument, you should use `GraphQLInputObjectType` instead of `GraphQLObjectType`. And keep in mind that GraphQL is strongly type based, so you're not allowed to use a generic `GraphQLObjectType` as arg type and then dynamically query args. You have to explicitly define all possible fields in this input object (and choose which of them would be mandatory and which not)

Try use this approach:

```
// your arg input object
var inputType = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
    name: 'paymentInput',
    fields: {
        user: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
        },
        order: {
            type: GraphQLString
        },
        ...another fields
    }
});

var Query = new graphQL.GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: {
        payment: {
            type: graphQL.GraphQLString,
            args: {
                data: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(inputType) }
            },
            resolve: function (_, args) {
                // There will be more data here,
                // but ultimately I want to return a string
                return 'success!';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Lord Dave. I ended up changing it to a `mutation` and specifying fields. Btw, two more questions: `1)` Is there a better way to write my POST query than `encodeURIComponent('{ payment ( data: { user : "test" } )}');` ? This gets unwieldy manually specifying each field if the object is large. `2)` GraphQL seems to required a `Query`, even though I only need a `Mutation`. Am I required to always have a query or is there an options somewhere?

Comment: `1)` I presume you are using a jquery ajax to make a graphql calls according to your given example. Unfortunately I can't help you with this since in my project I am using a `Relay` on `ReactJS` frontend, which is responsible for this.
 
`2)` Apparently, `Query` is always required in schema. Take a look at the `graphql-js` source [code](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/type/schema.js#L58)

I hope I've helped you with at least something

Comment: Thank you!!! Two years since this post and the documentation still doesn't make it clear. I wasted an entire day until I saw this post. Thanks for the solution @lorddave!