# Graphql object ( or JSON) as filter argument

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-client, apollo-server

Is it possible to have a JSON object as filed in filter arguments. Something like:

```
    Query{
      building(location:{lon,lat}){
        name,...
      }
    }
```

I need to pass location, and I would like to pass it as js object ( to apollo client) or as stringified JSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GraphQL.js Node/Express: How to pass object as GraphQL query argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722888/graphql-js-node-express-how-to-pass-object-as-graphql-query-argument)

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39759988/apollo-graphql-mutation-object-argument) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39114417/graphql-args-error-argument-type-must-be-input-type-but-got-function-graphqlob)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [input types](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/schema/#input-types) to achieve that. You need to edit your schema

```
type Query {
    building(location: Location): Building
}

input Location {
    lon: String
    lat: String
}
```

Then you can post your query like this

```
query {
  building(location: {lon:"100.332680",lat:"5.416393"}) {
    name,...
  }
}
```